# Caffe constant multiply layer

Tags: machine-learning, caffe

How can I define *multiply constant* layer in Caffe (like MulConstant in Torch).  I need to add it predefined const to existing network.
Caffe fails to parse my attempt to scale everything by 0.85:

```
layers {
  name: "caffe.ConstantMul_0"
  type: "Eltwise"
  bottom: "caffe.SpatialConvolution_0"
  top: "caffe.ConstantMul_0"
  eltwise_param {
    op: MUL
    coeff: 0.85
  }
}
```

Comment: Clarified wording

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do with [Power Layer](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html), just set up power to 1 and scale to whatever you need:

```
layer {
  name: "caffe.ConstantMul_1"
  bottom: "caffe.SpatialConvolution_3"
  top: "caffe.ConstantMul_1"
  type: "Power"
  power_param {
    power: 1
    scale: 0.85
    shift: 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eltwise layer can do three types of operations - PROD, SUM, MAX. You can see more about this [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto)

In your case, the `op` paramter should be set as PROD.

```
layers {
  name: "caffe.ConstantMul_0"
  type: "Eltwise"
  bottom: "caffe.SpatialConvolution_0"
  top: "caffe.ConstantMul_0"
  eltwise_param {
    op: MUL
    coeff: 0.85
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but that doesn't work: "Check failed: MinBottomBlobs() <= bottom.size() (2 vs. 1) Eltwise Layer takes at least 2 bottom blob(s) as input."
Seems, that caffe can multiply only two matrices, but not matrix and const... I don't know where I can ask, but it is totally not clear how to do that simple operation.