# How can I apply basic algebra in Caffe?

Tags: neural-network, caffe

I want the network output to be within the range of `(-0.5, 0.5)`, i.e. `-0.5` to the sigmoid output.

It's a simple operation but it seems not simple with Caffe.

Is adding another layer (that does nothing but subtracting `0.5` from the input) to Caffe the only way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Power layer to make a "multiply constant" layer.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075187/%D0%A1affe-constant-multiply-layer).

Comment: thank you much, just what I'm looking for is more of an "add constant" which can be done by the power layer as well